# Stop input from losing focus on Virtual keyboard click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've created a custom virtual keyboard for a kiosk application. The problem is every time you click on keyboard keys, input field loses its focus. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any code example?

Comment: has you a FormArray and are you iterating over formArray.values NOT over formArray.controls?

Comment: As demonstrated in below answer you can `focus` back on the <input/> `onfocusout` ie. when the user clicks elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

> You can shift the focus back as soon as the input loses out the focus on click on the virtual keyboard.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input')
input.focus() // focus on input on page load

function handleInput (key) {
 input.value += key // add key value to input
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleInput('a')">a</button>
<button onclick="handleInput('b')">b</button>
<button onclick="handleInput('c')">c</button>

<input onfocusout="this.focus()" id="input"/> <!-- focus on input back on onfocusout ie. when user click elsewhere -->
```

*Input is always in focus.*

Answer (score 1):

Prevents focusing the element then returns focus to the desired field.

```
$('#div').on('mousedown', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#field').focus();
});
```